# Detect monitor in windows 7?

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to get Windows 7 to detect a monitor using autohotkey?

I mean as if you went through control panel, display, detect monitor.

If my PC has been idle for sometime, it loses my HDTV.  If I'm upstairs I just go through control panel and re-detect. This solves the problem, however, I want to use autohotkey so I can re-detect using my remote in the living room.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jon

Comment: What steps do you use right now? (step by step).

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solutions and one of the answesr was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably, you need something like this...

```
Run, "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" shell32`.dll`,Control_RunDLL desk`.cpl
Sleep, 400
Send, !c ; Send Alt+c for deteCt
Sleep, 1000
Send, {Enter} ; Send Enter to close
Return
```

Comment: Sorry it took a while, had another issue to sort out.  The above code works perfectly.  Thank you for your help.  Jon

Answer (score 1):

This is a modified example from the [SysGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm) Documentation.

```
SysGet, MouseButtonCount, 43
SysGet, VirtualScreenWidth, 78
SysGet, VirtualScreenHeight, 79

SysGet, MonitorCount, MonitorCount
SysGet, MonitorPrimary, MonitorPrimary
Message .= "Monitor Count:`t" MonitorCount "`nPrimary Monitor:`t" MonitorPrimary
Loop, %MonitorCount%
{
    SysGet, MonitorName, MonitorName, %A_Index%
    SysGet, Monitor, Monitor, %A_Index%
    SysGet, MonitorWorkArea, MonitorWorkArea, %A_Index%
    Message .= "`n`nMonitor:`t#" A_Index "`nName:`t" MonitorName "`nLeft:`t" MonitorLeft "(" MonitorWorkAreaLeft " work)`nTop:`t" MonitorTop " (" MonitorWorkAreaTop " work)`nRight:`t" MonitorRight " (" MonitorWorkAreaRight " work)`nBottom:`t" MonitorBottom "(" MonitorWorkAreaBottom " work)"
}

msgbox % Message
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Robert, thank you for the answer (I can't comment your post directly yet).
I have cleaned up the code a little and make it work with other languages:

```
HOTKEY::
   Run, "C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" shell32`.dll`,Control_RunDLL desk`.cpl
   WinWaitActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass 
   SendInput, +{Tab 2}{Space}{Enter} ;Select & press "Detect" button, then press "OK" button
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the auto-detection feature of your graphics card through the advanced display properties or the driver management utility.
Usualy more and more graphic cards senting a signal to test if a monitor is lid or not, so they can "unplug" it.

Answer (score 0):

With autohotkey your can use [SysGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SysGet.htm).

```
SysGet, monitorCount, MonitorCount
```

There are also a bunch of other parameters that can be used. Check the link above.